# Please rename some tags for consistency

Tags: feature-request, tags, tag-synonyms

Across Stack Exchange, we usually go for plural tags for countable nouns, and for unabbreviated tags. Please rename the following tags for consistency (keeping synonyms as suitable, of course):

- [directory](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/directory) → [directories](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/directories)
- [symlink](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/symlink) → [symbolic-links](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/symbolic-links)
- [process](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/process) → [processes](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/processes)
- [partition](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/partition) → [partitions](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/partitions)
- [executable](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/executable) → [executables](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/executables)
- [distros](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/distros) → [distributions](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/distributions)

Pity we can't do that for [window](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/window). This tag shouldn't exist anyway; what's a good replacement (or set of replacements)? [window-manipulation](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/window-manipulation)?

Comment: Is this really true? On SO the singular versions are winning in all cases

Comment: @MichaelMrozek Browsing through [tag:tags] on MSO: [unclear](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/41501/tagging-as-singular-or-plural), [anecdotes](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97513/merge-value-type-into-value-types). [Jeff prefers plurals](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1788/merge-tags-tab-and-tabs/2357#2357).

Comment: I would suggest the opposite: prefer the singular form.

Comment: /symlink should stay as /symlinks if you really want to go for plural. But not for /symbolic-links. Because most people tend tii use the shorter form in all forms of speech.

Answer (score 1):

- [window](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/window) was used **13** times
- [window-manipulation](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/window-manipulation) was never used

I think we should delete [window-manipulation](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/window-manipulation). And since we use [x-server](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/x-server), maybe we should replace [window](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/window) with [x-client](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/x-client) ?

Comment: [tag:x-client] sounds like a process or application rather than a window. We use [tag:window] because it's there, but I don't think it's a good tag name, because it's too close to the completely different [tag:windows].

Comment: then maybe we can use [tag:x-window] ?

Comment: Confusingly close to [tag:x-window-system] (for which we use [tag:x11]).

Comment: what about [tag:gui] ?

Comment: too generic, that's more of an analog to [tag:command-line].