# Rename [monitor] to [monitors]

Tags: feature-request, tags, retag-request

[We're inconsistent as to whether we use singular or plural countable nouns in tag names.](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/856/please-rename-some-tags-for-consistency)

For [monitor](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/monitor) (as in a computer monitor, also called a screen or display), there's a risk of confusion with [monitoring](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/monitoring) (as in detecting certain events and reacting to them). [monitors](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/monitors) would be more clearly the noun and not the verb.

Please rename [monitor](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/monitor) to [monitors](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/monitors) (without leaving a synonym).

<sub>And please copy the tag wiki. Also, the tag wiki on [screen](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/screen) will need updating.</sub>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Done:

```
updating post history, 53 rows affected
updating posts, 32 rows affected
updating PostTags associations, 32 rows affected
removing/renaming old tag, 0 rows affected
updating count for master tag, 1 rows affected
tag remapping of [monitors] and [monitor] complete!
remapping 0 synonyms
0 favorite and ignored tags remapped!
Broadcasting tag-engine reload
```

The wikis are updated as well